# How to post a image arraybuffer using axios from electron?

Tags: node.js, axios, electron

I am using screenshot-desktop package in electron to get screenshot of my desktop. Its getting me a array buffer of the screenshot. Now I want to send this array buffer to the API which is in NodeJS. I am using Axios post method to send the data to my NodeJS API. I tried couple of things like fs.createReadStream and Blob but nothing work properly can any one provide a solution that how we can send array buffer from electron?